# How to iterate over a dictionary

Tags: python

```
In [1]: test = {}

In [2]: test["apple"] = "green"

In [3]: test["banana"] = "yellow"

In [4]: test["orange"] = "orange"

In [5]: for fruit, colour in test:
   ....:     print(fruit)
   ....:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-8930fa4ae2ac> in <module>()
----> 1 for fruit, colour in test:
      2     print(fruit)
      3 

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What I want is to iterate over `test` and get the key and value together.  If I just do a `for item in test:` I get the key only.

An example of the end goal would be:

```
for fruit, colour in test:
    print(f"The fruit {fruit} is the colour {colour}")
```

Comment: see `help(dict)`

Comment: Why not `for fruit in test: print "The fruit %s is the colour %s" % (fruit, test[fruit])` ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `items()` to get an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs from `test`:

```
for fruit, color in test.items():
    # do stuff
```

This is covered in [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

In Python 2, `items` returns a concrete list of such pairs; you could have used `iteritems` to get the same lazy iterable instead.

```
for fruit, color in test.iteritems():
    # do stuff
```

Comment: In Python 3, you will have to change `itemiter()` to `item()` `for fruit, color in test.items()`- since dict.iteritems() was removed and now dict.items() does the same thing

Comment: @user-asterix Thanks, I've updated the answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 14):

Change

```
for fruit, colour in test:
    print "The fruit %s is the colour %s" % (fruit, colour)
```

to

```
for fruit, colour in test.items():
    print "The fruit %s is the colour %s" % (fruit, colour)
```

or

```
for fruit, colour in test.iteritems():
    print "The fruit %s is the colour %s" % (fruit, colour)
```

Normally, if you iterate over a dictionary it will only return a key, so that was the reason it error-ed out saying "Too many values to unpack".
Instead `items` or `iteritems` would return a `list of tuples` of `key value pair` or an `iterator` to iterate over the `key and values`.

Alternatively you can always access the value via key as in the following example

```
for fruit in test:
    print "The fruit %s is the colour %s" % (fruit, test[fruit])
```

Answer (score 4):

The normal `for key in mydict` iterates over keys. You want to iterate items:

```
for fruit, colour in test.iteritems():
    print "The fruit %s is the colour %s" % (fruit, colour)
```