# Can't access Second Item of Python object

Tags: python, object

I have a dictionary of items, where the list is formatted to be 
{(x,y): z, (x,y):z...} where x and y are coordinates and z is a probability. I need to perform operations using the probability. How can I access those?

I tried things like

```
    for item in lst:
        print item[1]
```

However, that only returned the y coordinate. Attempting to print item[2] returned the error "Need more than 2 values to unpack"

Comment: How are you saying your data is in list ? Can you share what is your input and what are you expecting ?

Comment: You need to read a getting started with Python type of guide.

Comment: Also, it's 0-indexed... "(x, y)" is `item[0], item[1]`

Comment: `item[2]` would be the third thing, not the second.

Comment: Also that's a dict, not a list.

Comment: item[2] does not work either. I receive the error saying there needs to be more than 2 values to unpack

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589812/python-iterate-over-a-dictionary and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops

Comment: @SandeepLade sorry, it is a dictionary. I am looking for the proper way to access the second value in the dictionary. item[2] does not seem to work

Comment: @DMop Dict is not ordered, so u can't use indexing for it

Comment: iterating on a `dict` will run through its keys, try `list[item][1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using a dictionary, python can retrieve both names and values individually. For example for:

```
>>> a = {(1,2): 0.5, (2,3): 0.4}
>>> a.keys()
>>> [(1, 2), (2, 3)]

>>> a.values()
>>> [0.5, 0.4]
```

Therefore for you to perform calculations on the probabilities you need to do:

```
for item in a.values():
    print item
```

each item will output the values of your dictionary in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
list = {(x1, y1): z1, (x2, y2): z2, ...} # actually a dict
for (x, y), z in list.items():
    print x, y, z
```

or this:

```
list = {(x1, y1): z1, (x2, y2): z2, ...} # actually a dict
for z in list.values():
    print z
```

But you may be better off using a true  `list` instead of a `dict`. It's also best to avoid giving your variables names that match built-in Python components like `list`. So then you'd have something like this:

```
lst = [(x1, y1, z1), (x2, y2, z2), ...]
for x, y, z in lst:
    print x, y, z
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not have a lit, that is a dict, so you can access z by using coordinates as key:

```
my_dict = {(x,y): z, (x,y):z...}
my_dict[(x, y)]
```

In a for loop:

```
for probability in my_dict.values():
    print(probability)
```

I recommend you do not use the name list for this cause it is a built-in

Answer (score 1):

For item in list is getting one item at a time. So how can you access second item. Here is an example I made for you. Let say here is your dictionary d where coordinates 10,20 has prob 0.1 and 20,30 has prob 0.2

```
d = {(10,20):0.1, (20,30):0.2}
d.items() # this will print- dict_items([((10, 20), 0.1), ((20, 30), 0.2)])
d[(10,20)] # this will print 0.1
d[(20,30)] # this will print 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you present us here is indeed your data structure `{(x,y): z, (x,y):z...}` then you should iterate and unpack it in another fashion than you do:

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  4 2017, 06:09:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = {(1,2):0.5, (3,4):0.9}
>>> for coordinates, probability in l.items():
...     print(coordinates, probability)
...
(1, 2) 0.5
(3, 4) 0.9
```

See [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

If you want a list of tuples, you could transform it easily with

```
>>> [ (coordinates, probabilities) for coordinates, probabilities in l.items() ]
[((1, 2), 0.5), ((3, 4), 0.9)]
```

In your version, you unpack the keys of the dictionary, which are a `tuple` of an `x` and a `y` coordinate. `print item[1]` references the `y` coordinate (python has `0`-based indexing), which is not, what you want.