# Finding Key using next() and iter()

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using Python 3.6. I want to get the keys and Values separately from the JSON Object. But When I try to use the method below, It gives me error

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

```
my_dictionary = [{
            "position": 0,
            "A": "Age"
        }, {
            "B": "Class",
            "position": 1
        }, {
            "C": "ID",
            "position": 2
        }, {
            "D": "Section",
            "position": 3
        }, {
            "E": "Height",
            "position": 4
        }, {
            "F": "Weight",
            "position": 5
        }, {
            "G": "Name",
            "position": 6
        }, {
            "position": 7,
            "H": "Jack"
        }, {
            "position": 8,
            "I": "Williams"
        }]
for tokn in my_dictionary:
    del tokn['position']
        
keys = [next(iter(x)) for x in my_dictionary]
# Error: values = [next(iter(y)) for x,y in prediction]
print(keys)
# print(values)
Output: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```

These are the keys. I want the values. But with the values code "Commented", I get:

> Error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

> Also, what can be done to decrease the complexity and make it efficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python iterate over a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589812/python-iterate-over-a-dictionary)

Comment: what is your _expected_ output? what is you _current_ output? something? an error?

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over a dictionary always gives you keys. If you want values, use the `.values()` method.

```
[next(iter(x.values())) for x in my_dictionary]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems quite confused. You delete key-value pairs from the dictionary just to avoid them when you want to access a "random element". A better approach is usually to "skip" them during iteration.

Also iterations over a dictionary are by default over the keys, however you can also iterate over the keys/values or key/values explicitly:

- `for key in x.keys()` for the keys (identical to `for key in x`)
- `for value in x.values()` for the values
- `for key, value in x.items()` for the keys and values

I suspect you wanted the `.items` given that you want to unpack it into two variables.

Just to show an alternative approach using `for` loops and conditionals:

```
keys = []
values = []
for inner_dictionary in my_dictionary:
    for key, value in inner_dictionary.items():
        if key != 'position':
            keys.append(key)
            values.append(value)
```

Without the `del` and `next(iter(...))` stuff.

You can write it as comprehension but it gets long-ish:

```
[v for d in my_dictionary for k,v in d.items() if k != 'position']
```